# Determining why this is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

Why $R_3 = \lbrace (1,2),(3,4)\rbrace$ is transitive?

It's like, transitive is said because there's $\{a,b\}$,$\{b,c\}$ then there will be $\{a,c\}$ right? But then, why is that one is said to be transitive?

Answer (score 4):

A transitive relation is one such that **if** we have $(a, b), (b, c) \in R$, **then** necessarily $(a, c)\in R$.

When we don't have $(a, b), (b, c) \in R$, then we $(a, c)$ need not be in a transitive relation $R$.

Put differently, a relation is transitive **unless** there exist $(a, b) , (b, c) \in R$, but $(a, c) \notin R$.

In your case, the relation is transitive because there are no pairs of the form $(a, b), (b, c) \in R_3$, so it *cannot fail* to be transitive. It is *vacuously* true that the relation is transitive.